# Calcular todas as distâncias

Tags: c, funções

Em um exercício, preciso calcular todas as distâncias entre pontos de coordenadas `(x,y)` que são lidos de um arquivo, sendo que o último ponto coincide com o primeiro. Cada ponto representa uma cidade que é representada pela seguinte estrutura:

```
typedef struct
{
    int x;
    int y;
} Cidade;
```

Um arquivo de entrada de exemplo pode ser visto abaixo:

```
24
(1,10)  (4,4)   (5,1)   (2,0)   (1,10)
(1,10)  (4,4)   (2,0)   (5,1)   (1,10)
(1,10)  (5,1)   (4,4)   (2,0)   (1,10)
(1,10)  (5,1)   (2,0)   (4,4)   (1,10)
(1,10)  (2,0)   (5,1)   (4,4)   (1,10)
(1,10)  (2,0)   (4,4)   (5,1)   (1,10)
(4,4)   (1,10)  (5,1)   (2,0)   (4,4)
(4,4)   (1,10)  (2,0)   (5,1)   (4,4)
(4,4)   (5,1)   (1,10)  (2,0)   (4,4)
(4,4)   (5,1)   (2,0)   (1,10)  (4,4)
(4,4)   (2,0)   (5,1)   (1,10)  (4,4)
(4,4)   (2,0)   (1,10)  (5,1)   (4,4)
(5,1)   (4,4)   (1,10)  (2,0)   (5,1)
(5,1)   (4,4)   (2,0)   (1,10)  (5,1)
(5,1)   (1,10)  (4,4)   (2,0)   (5,1)
(5,1)   (1,10)  (2,0)   (4,4)   (5,1)
(5,1)   (2,0)   (1,10)  (4,4)   (5,1)
(5,1)   (2,0)   (4,4)   (1,10)  (5,1)
(2,0)   (4,4)   (5,1)   (1,10)  (2,0)
(2,0)   (4,4)   (1,10)  (5,1)   (2,0)
(2,0)   (5,1)   (4,4)   (1,10)  (2,0)
(2,0)   (5,1)   (1,10)  (4,4)   (2,0)
(2,0)   (1,10)  (5,1)   (4,4)   (2,0)
(2,0)   (1,10)  (4,4)   (5,1)   (2,0)
```

Implementei as duas funções abaixo para calcular as distâncias:

```
float Distancia(Cidade cA, Cidade cB)
{
    int distanciaX = pow(cA.x - cB.x, 2);
    int distanciaY = pow(cA.y - cB.y, 2);
    float distancia = sqrt(distanciaX + distanciaY);
    return distancia;
}

float Distancias(Cidade *C, int numeroCidades)
{
    int i;
    float total = 0;
    for(i = 0; i < numeroCidades; i++)
    {
        if(i == numeroCidades - 1)
       {
            total = total + Distancia(C[i], C[0]);
        }
        else
        {
            total = total + Distancia(C[i], C[i+1]);
        }
    }
    return printf("Distancia Total: %f\n\n", total);
}
```

Por fim, criei uma outra função que armazena todas essas distâncias calculadas:

```
void ArmazenaDistancias(Cidade C[], int numeroCidade)
{
     int i;
     float distancias[TotalViagens(numeroCidade)];
     for(i = 0; i < TotalViagens(numeroCidade); i++)
     {
         distancias[i] = Distancias(C, numeroCidade);
     }
 }
```

Porém, ao imprimir os valores, todas as distâncias calculadas são resultado apenas da primeira viagem. Ou seja, ele calcula todas as 24 viagens, mas todas com o valor da primeira. Há algo de errado nas funções? Gostaria de saber o que pode ser mudado para que cada `distancias[i]` guarde o valor de cada viagem para que, no final, eu possa descobrir a menor distância (para cada cidade inicial diferente).

Comment: Possível duplicata de [Dúvida na impressão de resultados](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/240160/d%c3%bavida-na-impress%c3%a3o-de-resultados)

Comment: Renan, você quer guardar a distância das 24 cidades para todas as outras 24 cidades? 576 possibilidades então?

Comment: Renan, como o Jefferson falou no comentário acima, não ficou bem claro o que você deseja fazer. Mas olhando por cima, parece-me que você precisa de um for encadeado para fazer a relação da 1ª cidade com todas as outras; depois a 2ª cidade com as demais, e assim por diante.

Comment: O problema consiste em calcular todas as rotas possíveis entre n cidades. Nesse exemplo, são 4 cidades, portanto 4! = 24 possibilidades. Lembrando que a última cidade é sempre o ponto de partida. A minha dúvida neste tópico é como calcular a distância de cada possibilidade (cada linha do arquivo de entrada). Ou seja, 24 distâncias totais a serem calculadas. Preciso calcular a menor distância para cada cidade inicial diferente. Por exemplo, para a cidade (1,10) como ponto inicial, qual a menor rota? Para a cidade (4,4), qual a menor rota? E assim por diante. Desculpas por não ter sido claro.